# How to deserialise a proto that was received as a byte[]

Tags: serialization, byte, protobuf-net

I am using the Spring.Rest framework.

If we receive a 402, the body will contain a proto which in turn will contain various error information.

The Exception raised on a 402 is an instance of Spring.Rest.Client.HttpClientErrorException.
The response within the exception is an instance of Spring.HttpResponseMessage.
The Body within the response is of type byte[].
This means I have a byte[] while the Deserialiser is expecting a Stream.

In order to deserialise the proto contained in the body I have done the following:

```
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
mStream.Write(exception.Response.Body,0,exception.Response.Body.Length);
var proto = Serializer.Deserialize<XXXRestProtoException>(mStream);
```

when I inspect the proto returned, its properties are all null.
Is my approach correct, or do I need to do more before presenting the Stream to the Deserialize method?

We have confirmed that the proto definitions used on Client and Server are in sync and the body is well formed on the server.

The Stream produced by this code has the same length and contents as the given byte[], which in turn matches the content-length header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `Write` to a stream, then the `Position` is left at the **end** of the stream; 2 simple options:

1. rewind the stream; between the `Write` and the `Deserialize`, put:

   ```
   ms.Position = 0;
   ```
2. initialize the stream from the blob:

   ```
   MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(exception.Response.Body);
   ```

I'd usually use the latter.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that was my issue.

Comment: To be precise we needed to use new MemoryStream(exception.Response.Body);
Resetting the position didn't work.